# On Demand Cloud Audio Transcription service?

Tags: cloud, audio

Is there an on demand audio transcription service that will convert speech to text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not say whether you want human or machine transcription. For machine transcription, there is [Nexiwave](http://nexiwave.com/). I haven't tried them, but they seem to be somewhat further ahead than other solutions. And they have an API.

Answer (score 1):

[www.onehourtranslation.com/transcription/](http://www.onehourtranslation.com/transcription/) is offering transcripts now.